# Using Excel 365, How to generate a random list of random items, without duplicates, while potentially ignoring certain rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using Excel from Office 365, I want to generate a list of random items, without duplicates, while potentially ignoring certain rows.  I can successfully achieve everything but the last part - "while potentially ignoring certain rows".

I have a spreadsheet that has the following:

Column A - a list of names

Column C - the Rand() function copied down for all rows that exist for A

Column D - the formula: =@INDEX($A$2:$A$39,RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$39))

All of the above successfully provides a random list of non-duplicated values from column A.  What I want to do is add a Column B, and ignore all values in A, if B has an "X" in the cell.  So I want a random list of non-duplicated values from A, but when that random list is generated, it should ignore all values in A if B has an "X" in the corresponding cell.

Assume I do NOT want to use VBA.  Can this be achieved by somehow modifying my existing formula?

Comment: Use `Filter` on `A:B` first, then apply your logic the the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **E2** enter:

```
=FILTER(D2:D39,B2:B39<>"X")
```

[image]

You should be aware that your posted formula for column **D** does allow duplicates.  This can be addressed by using :

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(D2:D39,B2:B39<>"X"))
```

In **E2**

**EDIT#1:**

Since you are using Excel 365, this can be simplified.  With cols **A** and **B** as before, in **C2** enter:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A39,B2:B39<>"X"))
```

This does the filtering and also extracts only the unique values.  In **D2** enter:

```
=SORTBY(C2#,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(C2#)))
```

This randomizes the contents of column **C**.

*(No VBA was used in the making of this answer.)*

Comment: Thank you very much.  This does precisely what I want, and is a more concise, clever answer than I had !